# Issue with Nested List when data does not contain 'text' node

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to render Nested list such that when I drill down back button shows name of parent node. I tried it but looks like if the JSON I am getting doesn't have node with name `text`, it won't work.

Here is the [fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ECuRQ#CbW3N) with local data (in my app I am using store to fetch this from service so I don't have control over name of nodes)

Please note back button where title is not populated when you go down the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this `displayField` config of `NestedList` where you can specify which `field` to be used to set `title` and **item text** . By default it is set to `text` but you can specify it to be one of your `model` field.

Here's working [fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ho8fi) based on your example. Only change is in `config` of NestedList at bottom.

But, if you are overriding `getItemTextTpl`  or `getTitleTextTpl`, this config will be ignored.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for.